# How to query Alert System Enable mail profile properties

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-agent

In order to send automated job failure notifications from SQL Server Agent, you must configure Database Mail and then to to `SQL Agent properties > Alert System > Mail Session > Enable mail profile` to configure the `mail system` and `mail profile` to be used to send the email notifications.  We have many servers, and would like to setup a central cross-server job that ensures that the `Enable mail profile` option is checked across various servers, because otherwise, the scheduled jobs fail silently without sending an email notification.

Is there a *supported* way to query the `msdb` database to get to these settings using T-SQL (or by some other way programmatically)?

Running a SQL Profiler trace while bringing up the properties page in the SQL Server Agent UI shows references to `msdb.dbo.sp_get_sqlagent_properties` which is an undocumented procedure (I would prefer to use documented objects to help future-proof our solution), and several calls to  `master.dbo.xp_instance_regread` which I would imagine the reg keys could change per each SQL Server instance installation.

Does anyone know of a way to query to check whether the `enable mail profile` option is configured, and also retrieve the `mail profile` that is designated in the SQL Agent Alert System configs? Most of our servers are SQL Server 2008 R2, with some SQL 2012.  I would prefer SQL 2008+ support.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Future-proofing is a very wise idea :). As you noted, both xp_regread and xp_instance_regread are also undocumented. And http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b83dd2c1-afde-4342-835f-c1debd73d9ba/xpregread explains your concern (plus, it offers you an alternative).

Your trace and your run of sp_helptext 'sp_get_sqlagent_properties' are a good start. The next thing to do is run sp_helptext 'sp_helptext', and note its reference to sys.syscomments. BOL sys.syscomments topic redirects you to sys.sql_modules, and that points to the next step. Unfortunately for your needs, just one row (for 'sp_get_sqlagent_properties') will be returned by running USE msdb; SELECT object_name(object_id) FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE definition LIKE '%sp_get_sqlagent_properties%'. I thus assume you are out of luck - there appears to be no alternative, publicly documented, module (sproc). My assumption could be wrong :).

I deduce that xp_reg% calls exist for client (SMO, SSMS, etc.) needs, such as setting/getting agent properties. More importantly (for your needs), your sp_helptext run also reveals SSMS (a client) is using a registry store (i.e. not a SQL store). Unfortunately, I must deduce (based upon an absence of proof from a library search) that those keys (and their values) are also not documented...

The above appears to put you in a pickle. You could decide "if we are going to rely upon undocumented registry keys, we might as well rely on the undocumented calls to read them", but I won't recommend that:). You could also file a feature request at https://connect.microsoft.com/ (your need is clear), but because your need concerns a client-side feature request, I do not recommend holding your breath while waiting for a fix :).

Perhaps it is time to step back and take a look at the bigger picture:

- How often can that key be changed, and how often will this process poll for that change?
- Email uses a mail primitive. Sender: "Dear recipient, did you get my mail?" Recipient: "Dear sender, did you send me mail?" Disabling an email profile is not the only reason for an email failure.

Would a different approach be more useful, when compared to periodically checking a key?

One approach would be to periodically send "KeepAlive" email. If the "KeepAlive" email isn't periodically received, maybe that key was tweaked, maybe the Post Office is on a holiday, or maybe something else (equally bad) happened.  Plus, this approach should be fully supported, documented, and be future-proof. Who knows how and what keys will be used in the next version of SQL Server Agent?

The first bullet isn't addressed (neither would it be addressed by periodically checking a key), and perhaps you have additional needs (worth mentioning on MS connect).

Comment: Thanks Bill!  The more I have researched this issue, the more it appears that using the undocumented system procedures are the way to explicitly check the SQL Agent *configs*, but your idea of a "keep-alive" email if very interesting and also addresses other mail possible mail failures!  I think I'll give that shot (in addition to querying the sysmail *documented* log tables for failures).  I could setup a "Confirm Database Mail" job where the only job step fails (on purpose) and then monitor the on failure mailbox to make sure an email is received based on a given schedule.

Comment: Then I just have to decide how to notify my group that the email notifications aren't working if the issue is indeed that email is down, haha

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to do this using PowerShell and `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobServer`.

Here is the PowerShell script I wrote to check if SQL Agent mail alerts are enabled, and to make sure that SQL Agent is set to Auto startup when the server reboots.  This works works with local or remote SQL instances.

```
# usage examples
Check-SQLAgentConfiguration -InstanceName 'localhost\sql2014'
Check-SQLAgentConfiguration -InstanceName 'RemoteServerName'


function Check-SQLAgentConfiguration{
    param([string]$InstanceName='localhost')

    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null;

    $smosrv = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($InstanceName);
    $smosrv.ConnectionContext.ConnectTimeout = 5; #5 seconds timeout.
    $smosrv.ConnectionContext.ApplicationName = 'PowerShell Check-SQLAgentConfiguration';
    "Server: {0}, Instance: {1}, Version: {2}, Product Level: {3}" -f $smosrv.Name, $smosrv.InstanceName, $smosrv.Version, $smosrv.ProductLevel;

    # NOTE: this does not seem to ever fail even if SQL Server is offline.
    if(!$smosrv){"SQL Server Connection failed";  return $null;}   

    $agent = $smosrv.JobServer;

    if(!$agent -or $agent -eq $null){
        throw "Agent Connection failed";  
        return -2;
    }

    $agentConfigErrMsg = "";

    if($agent.AgentMailType -ne "DatabaseMail"){ $agentConfigErrMsg += " AgentMailType: " + $agent.AgentMailType + "; "; }
    if(!$agent.DatabaseMailProfile){$agentConfigErrMsg += " DatabaseMailProfile: " + $agent.DatabaseMailProfile + "; ";}
    if($agent.SqlAgentAutoStart -ne "True"){$agentConfigErrMsg += " SqlAgentAutoStart: " + $agent.SqlAgentAutoStart + " ServiceStartMode: " + $agent.ServiceStartMode + "; "; }

    if($agentConfigErrMsg.length -gt 0){
       $agentConfigErrMsg = "Invalid SQL Agent config! " + $agentConfigErrMsg; 
       throw $agentConfigErrMsg;
       return -1;
    }

    <##
    #for debugging:
    "Valid: "
    "AgentMailType:" + $agent.AgentMailType;
    "DatabaseMailProfile: " + $agent.DatabaseMailProfile;
    "ServiceStartMode: " + $agent.ServiceStartMode;
    "SqlAgentAutoStart: " + $agent.SqlAgentAutoStart;
    #"SqlAgentMailProfile: " + $agent.SqlAgentMailProfile;
    #>

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL 2008R2 uses Service-broker like queues for mail processing (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  In our environments I check that the corresponding queue exists and is active.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.sys.service_queues
WHERE name = N'ExternalMailQueue' 
AND is_receive_enabled = 1;
```

This table is listed online (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187795%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Testing shows that this makes the required transition as we went from new instance -> enabled mail -> mail switched off and back again.

Comment: Is this service queue created when database mail is enabled or when SQL Agent mail profile is enabled? I'm not at my computer right and can check later but my suspicion is that it would be created when SQL Server database mail is enabled which is a little different than what I'm looking for in this case. I will give it a shot in the morning and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I confirmed that the ExternalMailQueue service queue is not affected by changing the *SQL Agent Alert system* settings, and is tied to *SQL Server Database Mail* setups. You have msdb.dbo.sysmail_* tables for querying Database mail setups. However, I'm interested in getting the SQL Agent Alert system properties (the values you see when you right click on SQL agent > properties > Alert system > Enable Mail profile and mail profile value).